# I'm getting a Segmentation Fault Error when wrapping vector<Mat> in C

Tags: c++, c, opencv

At the bottom of the page is the whole code I'm running for reference. I'm trying to wrap `vector<Mat>` in C, I already wrapped `vector<Point2f>` in C and I'm wrapping `vector<Mat>` the same.  The Point2f version runs fine but the Mat version gets a Segmentation Fault error(core dumped).

Here is my vector wrapper:

```
    vector_Point2f* std_carrayTovectorp2f(Point2f* a, size_t len) {
        vector<Point2f>* v = new vector<Point2f>;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            v->push_back(a[i]);
        return v;
    }
```

Here is my vector wrapper:

```
  vector_Mat* std_carrayTovectorm(Mat* a, size_t len) {
            vector<Mat>* v = new vector<Mat>;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            v->push_back(a[i]);
        return v;
    }
```

See they are both wrapped the same. I need to keep the `Mat* a` input parameter and the `vector_Mat*` return the same.  Plus keep the same functionality, everything else can be changed. Any help is appreciated.

The entire code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

typedef vector<Point2f> vector_Point2f;
typedef vector<Mat> vector_Mat;

vector_Mat* std_carrayTovectorm(Mat* a, size_t len) {
    vector<Mat>* v = new vector<Mat>;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        v->push_back(a[i]);
    return v;
}

vector_Point2f* std_carrayTovectorp2f(Point2f* a, size_t len) {
    vector<Point2f>* v = new vector<Point2f>;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        v->push_back(a[i]);
    return v;
}

int main()
{
  Mat* m, n, o;

  vector_Mat* v = std_carrayTovectorm(m, 1);
  cout << v;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you have a reason why you're dynamically allocating your vector object. Just like there must be a reason you're invoking `std_carrayTovectorm` with an indeterminate parameter `m`. I just can't think of a reason for *either*.

Comment: @WhozCraig...can you show me where I'm in error exactly?

Answer (score 2):

`m` is uninitialized when it is passed to `std_carrayTovectorp2f()`.

Comment: std_carrayTovectorm you mean

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks for replying, can you expand on what you  mean by "m is uninitialized when it is passed to std_carrayTovectorp2f()" I mean can you show me where exactly in my code the error is

Comment: @user3411335: You have: `Mat* m;` which creates but does not initialize a pointer. Then `vector_Mat* v = std_carrayTovectorm(m, 1);` passes the uninitialized pointer to `std_carrayTovectorm()`. The first argument isn't a reference to a pointer, so the function is given an indeterminate value — it isn't guaranteed to be NULL (or `nilptr`), or any other value. It would be different if you had `Mat m` (as you have `Mat n;` and `Mat o;` — you _do_ know that those two aren't pointers, don't you, and that's why people don't like the `Mat* m` notation); then you'd have a default initialized `Mat`.